# Using pipeline features of dplyr to export data as data.frame object in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in data.frame and I am gonna try pipeline feature of dplyr packages to do few pipeline operation in R. For example, given dataframe objects, first I will do subset, then export as csv files format. I am studying the feature of dplyr packages, so not perfectly understand this. Any help ?
Here is the simple reproducible example for simulation:

```
a <- GRanges(
  seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), c(3, 2, 1, 2)),
  ranges=IRanges(seq(1, by=9, len=8), seq(7, by=9, len=8)),
  rangeName=letters[seq(1:8)], score=sample(1:20, 8, replace = FALSE))
```

I do subsetting first:

```
a %>% subset(pvalue < 1e-4 & pvalue > 1e-9)
```

then wants to do several pipeline operation by using feature of dplyr:

```
a %>% subset(pvalue < 1e-4 & pvalue > 1e-9) %>% write.table(x, "foo.csv") %>% as.data.frame(x)
```

but I have an error when I do second step. If I need to do several pipeline work like result of first is used in the second, how can I proceed this in R by using dplyr packages ? Thanks

Comment: If you need to write out in the middle of a chain, use magrittr's `%T>%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract several different subsets and write them out, you may want to use `group_by` and `do`. First create a categorical variable that splits up your data into the subsets you want. Here's an example that works:

```
iris %>% mutate(
        slcat    = cut(Sepal.Length, c(0, 4, 5, 6, 8)),
        filename = paste0("file", slcat, ".csv")
      ) %>% 
      group_by(slcat) %>% 
      do(result = write.csv(., file = .$filename[1]))
```

Comment: I already accept the answer from Vincent. In this circumstances, should I accept yours also? Both of answer is feasible for me. I thank you

Comment: this one is fine ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `iris`, to make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) you can:

```
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 5.2) %>% write.table("foo.csv")
```

Some side remarks:

- `subset` is more a base R approach. Why not using [`dplyr`'s verbs](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), eg `filter`, `select`, etc. ?
- The pipe arguments (it's more a [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) than a `dplyr` operator now), throws the left hand side as the first argument on the right hand side, so `write.table(x, ...)` cannot work as intended.
- as `dplyr` works with `data.frame`s, you do not need `as.data.frame`

Comment: Thank you for this quick respond. Is there any existing thread to explain pipeline feature of dplyr more specifically? I am wondering I need to look at it and learn.

Comment: See link above/[`magrittr`'s vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html). The perfect place to start ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I will go through with it.